# Increase factotum spell casting pool

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, spellcasting

A factotum (3.5e dungeonscape) can "fake" casting spell with the ability arcane dilettante.

This allows to spend inspiration points to "cast" spells from the sorcerer/wizard spell list as spell-like ability.

The limitations are three fold :

- number of spell per day capped by the aforementioned ability advancement (up to 8 at level 20)
- max spell level also capped (up to 7th at level 18
- only one spell of the maximum level (the rest may be distributed however the player likes)

The question is : is there any official (3/3.5e) proposition to circumvent (at least partially) these limitations or to increase the limit ? (Item, rule, feat ect..)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Cool question, factotum is fun and I hope we can help. But I’m a little unsure what exactly you want: when you ask for “any proposition,” are you referring to official statements changing it, official options (feats, items, etc.) allowing one to increase it, non-official recommendations for a DM to change it (houserule), or non-official options to improve it (homebrew)?

Comment: If your question gets "closed", don't worry it is a most often a temporary measure to prevent bad answers when we lack the information to provide good answers.

Comment: Thank you for the introduction,I hope the edit clarified the question.

Comment: @Alex Yup, perfect, thanks so much! We’re at 4/5 reopen votes, so you should be good to go pretty soon. Then it’ll just be about trying to find an answer (which, unfortunately in this case, I suspect will be harder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I could figure out, Factotum did not receive any support that would provide tools for expanding the Arcane Dilettante feature directly - mostly because it received little direct support outside of Dungeonscape itself.

Part of this is that the restriction is defined as, "Once you have used a spell, you cannot use it again until you have rested for 8 hours." This isn't the standard per-day text, so feats that increase your per-day use limit on spell-like abilities won't help by RAW.

While not directly related to bypassing these limits, you can use Meta-spell-like feats like Quicken Spell-Like Ability from the Monster Manual to enhance your use of the feature.

Comment: You could, however, circumvent them with magical items.  A factotum could easily use things like scrolls, wands (eternal or otherwise), and rings of spell storing.

Comment: That was exactly what i was afraid of... I'll leave the question open for a week or so to see if anybody can add to this , just in case.